# Changing input type="tel" to password field using Angular 2/Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I want to change the input type `tel` to `password` field using Angular 2/Ionic 2.

I have a pin number field which will take number as input and I want to change the number to password field once the keypress event trigger.

I tried in the following way but the **keypad** is closing after enter the first number.

```
import { Component, Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

  @Directive({
      selector: '.inputmask'
    })    
    export class MyDirective {
       @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event.target'])
        onFocus(target) {
          target.type = 'password';
        }
        /*@HostListener('focusout', ['$event.target'])
        onFocusout(target) {
          target.type = 'tel';
        }*/
    }
```

And my template:

```
<ion-input type="tel" [formControl]="aadhaarno" class="inputmask">
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect use for `ViewChild`. It can be used to get reference to HTML element from DOM in your component so you can alter it. First, you need to add template variable to input element which will be used to get reference to it:

```
<ion-input #myInput type="tel" [formControl]="aadhaarno" class="inputmask">
```

Then in your component you have to import `ViewChild` and use it to get reference to input element in DOM:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('myInput')
myInput: any;
```

Then you create a function which will use `myInput` variable (it now has reference to input) to change its type to `password` and call it somewhere:

```
changeInput() {
this.myInput.nativeElement.type = "password";
}
```

Here's [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SQQxsTYGeZXPk7MsxhNN?p=preview).

Comment: You should not use the native element directly. you should use the Renderer service. you can read here https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi47Z-rvf3PAhXBCMAKHUQlDKcQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2F%40NetanelBasal%2Fangular-2-explore-the-renderer-service-e43ef673b26c&usg=AFQjCNE76-MhvXaGyWVj27RLykJVBSyLAg&bvm=bv.136811127,d.bGs why

Comment: @PatrickJane If I understood correctly, it is perfectly fine to use `nativeElement` directly if you are developing browser application. `The problem with this approach is that when we access the native element directly we are giving up on Angular’s DOM abstraction and miss out on the opportunity to be able to execute also in none-DOM environments such as: native mobile, native desktop, web worker or server side rendering.
Remember that Angular is a platform, and the browser is just one option for where we can render our app.`